# How to add a new column with text fields to WooCommerce Cart List?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

[image]
[image]
As attached images.  How to add a new column with text fields to WooCommerce Cart List?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This requires you to override WooCommerce templates:

1) **First read:** [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to understand how you can change some templates copying them to your active theme folder

2) **Copy the template** `templates/cart/cart.php` located in your Woocommerce plugin to your active theme in `woocommerce/cart/cart.php` *(so not in a "template" subfoder).*

3) **Open edit the template** `cart.php` and make the necessary changes in the html structure, adding your custom column and related php code.

Comment: As the screenshot: https://imgur.com/8gsyGbI
I can add the "Requirement" column by copying the codes from "product-quantity", but I have know idea how to customize related PHP code and make the text field works with WooCommerce...

Comment: @Green In StackExchange Wordpress development we don't code it for you… You need to try to code it yourself and if you have some issue on your code, you can ask a question providing your code. If you don't know how to code, you should hire a developer.